# gdiplus.dll not found on Android Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, dll, gdi+, aforge

The issue i am facing is that i am using AForge Library for image processing on Unity Platform. I got the code working on Unity Editor but when i run the code on Android phone, it produces log such as

```
07-20 13:51:43.168 21178-21261/? D/Unity: Unable to lookup library path for 'gdiplus.dll', native render plugin support disabled.
07-20 13:51:43.169 21178-21261/? E/Unity: Unable to find gdiplus.dll
07-20 13:51:43.182 21178-21261/? D/Unity: Unable to lookup library path for 'libc', native render plugin support disabled.
07-20 13:51:43.182 21178-21261/? E/Unity: Unable to find libc
07-20 13:51:43.210 21178-21261/? E/Unity: DllNotFoundException: gdiplus.dll
                                              at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
                                            at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                          Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus
                                            at System.Drawing.Image.InitFromStream (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                            at System.Drawing.Image.LoadFromStream (System.IO.Stream stream, Boolean keepAlive) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                            at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                            at AForge.Imaging.Image.FromFile (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                            at Load_Scene.CropImage () [0x000a2] in /Users/taskeenashraf/Development/GUI/Assets/Scripts/Load_Scene.cs:78 
                                            at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () [0x00017] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Unit
```

I have searched a lot on web and people are saying that you cannot use gdiplus.dll on android as it is windows native. But i used its version on MAC to run Unity. Is there a way around.Tried adding the dll to unity Plugins Folder with no success. Exported the project to android studio and added dll there and built again with failure.

Answer (score 2):

There is no gdiplus.dll on Android. You *shouldn't* use any framework, or API that requires gdiplus.dll, or uses any class from Windows Form API in Unity. The reason behind this is that some of these API has dependencies on native or managed DLL that can only be found on Windows. One would have to complete re-write them for other platforms in order to get it to work and this is a complicated and time consuming job.

---

You can't use AForge Library with Unity unless you're only targeting desktop platforms. Since you're performing image processing, you should be using [**OpenCV**](https://opencv.org/platforms/) which supports both desktop platforms and mobile devices like Android and iOS. When using OpenCV, you have to write the code in C++ as a plugin then communicate with it with C#. If you're not a C++ programmer or you want to save yourself time, use an already made OpenCV plugin from Unity from the [assetstore](https://assetstore.unity.com/search?q=opencv&k=opencv).